# Python: Email content configuration file

Tags: python, random, ini

I would like to be able to have a configuration file with an assortment of content to be mailed out. Each email would need to contain a subject and a body, with new lines.

For example:

```
[Message_One]
Subject: Hey there
Body: This is a test
      How are you?
      Blah blah blah

      Sincerely,
      SOS

[Message_Two]
Subject: Goodbye
Body: This is not a test
      No one cares
      Foo bar foo bar foo bar

      Regards
```

How would I get this to work with Python as a config file to randomly select between the content and/or grab one by it's defined name (Message_One, Message_Two)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from re import match
from collections import namedtuple
from pprint import pprint
from random import choice

Mail = namedtuple('Mail', 'subject, body')

def parseMails(filename):
    mails = {}
    with open(filename) as f:
        index = ''
        subject = ''
        body = ''
        for line in f:
            m = match(r'^\[(.+)\]$', line)
            if m:
                if index:
                    mails[index] = Mail(subject, body)
                index = m.group(1)
                body = ''
            elif line.startswith('Subject: '):
                subject = line[len('Subject: '):-1]
            else:
                body += line[len('Body: '):]
        else:
            mails[index] = Mail(subject, body)
    return mails

mails = parseMails('mails.txt')
index = choice(list(mails.keys()))
mail = mails[index]
pprint(mail)
```

---

```
Mail(subject='Goodbye', body='This is not a test\nNo one cares\nFoo bar foo bar foo bar\nRegards\n')
```

- parse the mails
- random choice one mail

Comment: Thanks, worked as expected and allows me to make adjustments if needed.

Comment: Any idea why there is only one newline before Regards, instead of two?

Comment: @mikeyy `body += line[len('Body: '):]`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe like this:

```
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser
import random

conf = ConfigParser()
conf.read('test.conf')

mail = random.choice(conf.sections())
print "mail: %s" % mail
print "subject: %s" % conf.get(mail, 'subject')
print "body: %s" % conf.get(mail, 'body')
```

It's just a matter of selecting a random section name with `random.choice(conf.sections())`. The `random.choice` function will pick a random element from a sequence — the `sections` method will return all the section names, that is, `["Message_One", "Message_Two"]`. You then use that section name to grab the other values you need.

Comment: Thanks. Looks a lot more simplified than what kev was going toward, but both work as expected.

Comment: @mikeyy: if you have a config file in the ini file format, then you should use `ConfigParser` to read it — if you have something else, well then you'll have to roll your own code like kev did above.

Comment: I have something else and have decided to use kev's code. One thing I noticed between both of yours though, it didn't recognize the extra newline before Regards, it's just one break.